# how to notify user about update available for my application in windows phone marketplace for OS 7.1

Tags: marketplace

Can any one tell me the steps to be followed to notify users that there is an update for my windows phone 7.1 application at market place so that he can go any update it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you release an update in the marketplace then the platform will prompt the user automatically. If you want to force an update then the old version will need to poll a service at startup and alert the user that they should go to marketplace and get the new version